# JavaScript loops through both if and else, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
if (manager.getProductType() === manager.TYPE_HARDWARE) {
    anotherManager.setTransactionType(manager.TYPE_HARDWARE);

} else {
    anotherManager.clearAllTransactionTypes();
}
```

For some reason, both the if and the else execute when I debug and trace in firebug. Any ideas what might be causing this?

manager.getProductType() evaluates to "HARDWARE"
manager.TYPE_HARDWARE evaluates to "HARDWARE"

Comment: *"For some reason, both the if and the else execute when I debug and trace in firebug..."* Not unless you're calling the code twice and `getProductType` changes in-between, not with that code. Something else must be going on.

Comment: it seem impossible both was executed. Can you put a console.log before the if, in the if and in the else to try?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is, "If you think you're seeing something impossible happening, clean your glasses."

Comment: It is impossible for code to execute both in `if` and `else` blocks. Maybe you're missing something.

Comment: I find Javascript to frequently have odd bugs, but this is beyond anything I've seen. I would try storing both `manager.getProductType()` and `manager.TYPE_HARDWARE` in their own variables and then comparing them with `==`. Also, if your actual code has more content within the true condition, perhaps your syntax within that block is incorrect and you're missing a `}` somewhere.

Comment: Can you recreate the symptom in a jsfiddle? It's likely something you're not seeing (since, as others have said, your symptom with the attached code is impossible) like your `setTransactionType` calling this piece of code again.

Comment: Are you doing more than one of these async calls? If yes, I have already had this issue and I can tell you more as response.